# PHP syntax error using a href in database list view

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, href

I would of thought this would be fairly simple to solve as it looks like my syntax is the issue here. I have searched through other simler stackoverflow problems but can't seem to solve this issue.

I am getting a  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\Active\Formula One\admin\list_products.php`  error.

Im doing a simple list view of the items in my database with the option of editing them through the use of the ID. Trying to add the `<a href>` tag into the table but cannot figure out the correct syntax to add it.

The link im trying to include is 
`<td><a href=" ../admin/admin.master.php?page=blog/edit_post.php&id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a> </td>`

Table is displayed as so;

```
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['prod_id'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['prod_sub_id'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['sale'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['picture'] . "</td>
<td><a href=" ../admin/admin.master.php?page=blog/edit_post.php&id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a> </td>
</tr>";
```

Thanks for any help, sorry this is such a simple problem but I have been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: So if you look at the syntax highlighting you are not seeing something suspicious in the last line with `<td>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not answer your question directly, but you should really avoid printing HTML tags. PHP alternate control structures dedicated to solve problems like this one.

So you should decouple HTML markup from PHP.

```
<table>

<!-- This is just an example, you shouldn't use mysql_* functions anymore -->
<!-- Use PDO or MySQLi instead -->
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resourse)) :?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['prod_id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['prod_sub_id'];?> </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['sale']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['picture'];?></td>
  <td><a href="<?php printf('../admin/admin.master.php?page=blog/edit_post.php&id=', $row['id']);?> ">Edit</a> </td>

</tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</table>
```

Consclusion:

1. This will make the code clear and readable
2. Easy to maintain
3. Gives you a confidence you won't have a syntax error like that one (in general)

Comment: great answer and recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

You must escape the double quote

```
<td><a href=\" ../admin/admin.master.php?page=blog/edit_post.php&id=" . $row['id'] . "\">Edit</a> </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that php doesn't realize that the `<a href="` is for a link, rather it is translating the double quote as the end of your string, as a result it's throwing you an error.

Change this line of code:

```
    "</td>
<td><a href=" ../admin/admin.master.php?page=blog/edit_post.php&id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a> </td>
</tr>";
```

To this:

```
'</td> // this needs a single quote in the beginning (not a double quoute)
<td><a href=" ../admin/admin.master.php?page=blog/edit_post.php&id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a> </td>
</tr>'; // this also needs a single quote
```

As you can see you were starting off with a double quote, and ending with a single quote making php confused.

Let us know if you need any more help